# WP Rest API - How to get featured image

Tags: javascript, api, json, plugin-json-api

I'm very new to this API, in fact I've only spent couple hours on it so far. I've done my research but cannot find anything about it...

The issue is, I can't seem to get the featured image of a post. The JSON returns `"featured_media: 0"`.

```
getPosts: function() {
  var burl = "http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
  var dataDiv = document.getElementById('cards');
  $.ajax({
    url: burl,
    data: data,
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=utf-8');
      }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      //question: data->featured_image: 0?!
      var theUl = document.getElementById('cards');
      for (var key in data) {
        //data[key]['']...
        //doing my stuff here
      }
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log('Error: '+e);
    }  
  });
}
```

I have definitely, set a featured image on the post but data returns:

[image: featured media?]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can get it without plugins by adding `_embed`as param to your query

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

Comment: this causes a problem when binding to it in an Angular binding, do to the `wp:` name of one of the nodes in the json path to the image.   I used the plugin from the other answer, which simplifies the path to the image.

Comment: cons: the JSON get heavier
pros: not install plugin, not call another http request
-> upvote

Comment: How should convert wp:featuredmedia to JSON? first I create wp class that contains featuredmedia. But it does not work.

Comment: You can access wp: by using this notation post._embedded['wp:term']

Comment: If you use a function to create the query parameters from an array and you can't use this function without combination of key and value, you can use `_embed` as key and `true` as value.

Answer (score 17):

I would NOT use the better rest API plugin. It did add featured images to the rest api but it also broke it.

This is the simplest solution I was able to find that actually worked. Add the following code to your functions.php:

```php
<?php

function post_featured_image_json( $data, $post, $context ) {
  $featured_image_id = $data->data['featured_media']; // get featured image id
  $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $featured_image_id, 'original' ); // get url of the original size

  if( $featured_image_url ) {
    $data->data['featured_image_url'] = $featured_image_url[0];
  }

  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'post_featured_image_json', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the name of the image with this path:

array_name._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at a plugin called [Better REST API Featured Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-rest-api-featured-images/). It adds the featured image URL to the original API response.

Comment: Thank you. Returns the URL which is handy. Any ideas why the plugin it self is not returning it? Am I doing something wrong or is it the API?

Comment: Its the API. Still early days. It will improve

Comment: Problem solved! It does actually return an ID of the image but I totally forgot I had the cache turned on! But anyway, that plugin is better as it returns the url directly.

Comment: @Devrim Glad you solved it! If this answer from Michael helped you, you can click the tick to the left of it to accept it to show others that this was the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I made a shortcut to my image by adding it directly to the API response.

---

```
//Add in functions.php, this hook is for  my 'regions' post type
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
  register_rest_field( 'regions', 'group', array(
         'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
         'schema'          => null,
      )
  );
}
```

---

```
//Use the post ID to query the image and add it to your payload
function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
  $post_id = $object['id'];
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
  $post_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );      
  $post_meta["group_image"] = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_image)[0];

  return $post_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this code in your theme's `functions.php` file and use this key for the featured image: `featured_image_url`

```
function post_featured_image_json( $data, $post, $context ) {
  $featured_image_id = $data->data['featured_media']; // get featured image id
  $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $featured_image_id, 'original' ); // get url of the original size

  if( $featured_image_url ) {
    $data->data['featured_image_url'] = $featured_image_url[0];
  }

  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'post_featured_image_json', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following way
....................

URL: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed`

image: `json["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"],`

It's working fine.try

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Yoast SEO plugin and found that the featured image URL is available in that.
After
URL: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed`

You can find featured image in: `yoast_head_json > robots > og_image > url`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Yoast SEO plugin
2. Get data from wp rest api to javascript

   ```
    async function fetchPosts() {
    const responce = await fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
    return responce.json();}
   ```
3. I am displaying 10 images in HTML (I used ID = posts in .html file)

   ```
    (async () => {
    var images = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var obj = `<img src = '${(await fetchPosts())[i].yoast_head_json.og_image[0].url}' width="500"></img>`;
        images += obj;
        document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = `${images}`
    }})()
   ```

Comment: Maybe edit your two answers together? It looks like they're giving the same solution.