# Display Post Featured Image along with Categories via WP Rest API

Tags: rest-api, json

I have a custom function that pulls in (3) posts from another Wordpress blog, and it's pulling them from specific categories I specify via a shortcode.

Now, with that said, I cannot get it to function and display the actual image, as I can only get it to show the featured Image's (media attachment's) ID itself.

Here is my functional code, which works except the image is not displayed, instead it's the images ID (numerical value)

```
function feedpuller_func($atts)
{
    $url = $atts['url'];

    $count = ($atts['count'])?$atts['count']:'3';

    if($atts['catid'])
    {
        $cat = '?categories='.$atts['catid'].'&per_page='.$count;
        $response = wp_remote_get( $url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed'.$cat );
    }
    else if ($atts['slug']) 
    {
        $slug = $atts['slug'];
        echo $url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug='.$slug;
        $responseslug = wp_remote_get($url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug='.$slug );
        $postdata = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $responseslug ) );
        if($postdata)
            $catid = $postdata[0]->id;
        else
            echo 'no record against this slug';
        if($catid)
        {
            $cat = '?categories='.$catid.'&per_page='.$count;
            $response = wp_remote_get( $url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed'.$cat );
        }

    }
    else 
        $cat = '';

    if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    if( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if( !empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base ) . $args['after_title'];
    }


    if( !empty( $posts ) ) {
        echo '<ul class="feedothersite">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) { //echo '<pre>'; print_r($post);
            echo '<li><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . '<img src="' . $post->featured_media . '">' . '<br>'. $post->title->rendered .'<br>'. $post->excerpt->rendered . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

add_shortcode("feedpuller","feedpuller_func");
```

EDIT: I do NOT want to use a plugin already made, and also I have tried the solutions at the related post, but my functions differ because I am displaying posts from certain categories, and typical posts are pulled and displayed without these parameters.

**Suggested Method (I know this works for regular posts)**

```
/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

**But mine are called like this:**

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug='.$slug
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP Rest API - How to get featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231137/wp-rest-api-how-to-get-featured-image)

Comment: I reviewed that post unfortunately I am not able to correctly process the functions with the way I am also pulling the specific category posts. I spent probably two hours on that post, trying different things too. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution with the help of a great friend. I will post it here if anyone else needs to utilize the fucntion. Again in summary, this function will display posts from another blog and you can enter specific category ID's from the other blog and also control how many posts are displayed.

```
function feedpuller_func($atts)
{
    $url = $atts['url'];

    $count = ($atts['count'])?$atts['count']:'3';
    $imgsize = (in_array($atts['img'], array('thumbnail','medium','large','full')))?$atts['img']:'thumbnail';

    if($atts['catid'])
    {
        $cat = '?_embed&categories='.$atts['catid'].'&per_page='.$count;
        $response = wp_remote_get( $url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'.$cat );
    }
    else if ($atts['slug']) 
    {
        $slug = $atts['slug'];
        echo $url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug=' . $slug;
        $responseslug = wp_remote_get($url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?slug=' . $slug);
        $postdata = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $responseslug ) );
        if($postdata)
            $catid = $postdata[0]->id;
        else
            echo 'no record against this slug';
        if($catid)
        {
            $cat = '?categories='.$catid.'&per_page='.$count;
            $response = wp_remote_get( $url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'.$cat );
        }

    }
    else 
        $cat = '';

    if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    if( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if( !empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base ) . $args['after_title'];
    }

    if( !empty( $posts ) ) {

        echo '<ul class="feedothersite">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) { //echo '<pre>'; print_r(); exit;
            $imgurl = $post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->media_details->sizes->$imgsize->source_url;
            if($imgurl)
                $img = '<img src="'.$imgurl.'">';
            else
                $img = '';

            echo '<div class="feedcontent"><a href="' . $post->link. '"><li><div class="feedimg">'.$img.'<div><h2>' . $post->title->rendered . '</h2></a></div></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

add_shortcode("feedpuller","feedpuller_func");
```

Shortcode value should follow [feedpuller url="http://othersite.com/" catid="22" count="4"] To display featured image, use: img="full" img="medium" or img="thumbnail"