# featured image not found in json from wp rest api

Tags: rest-api, json

I found that the image must be in the element featured media but I found another link that leads to another link contains this message in French means ( Sorry, you do not have permission to do that.)

[image: featured media]
 [image: rest forbidden]
please , how to solve this problem in wordPress ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP Rest API - How to get featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231137/wp-rest-api-how-to-get-featured-image)

Comment: @monsieur Moumni Same error here. Did you get any solution?

Comment: it's from my client .i contact him to solve the problem from wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Use the _Embed at the end of your JSON call. It should look something like this:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed.

That will give you both the json objects and include a the featured image url that you're looking for.

;-)