# No featured media in API request

Tags: wp-api

when I make a request to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed&categories=${categoryId}&per_page=${state.perPage}`

I get the following result

```
[                                                                                                            
  {
    id: 3,
    date: '2019-04-20T16:10:00',
    date_gmt: '2019-04-20T16:10:00',
    guid: {
      rendered: 'http://localhost/wordpress/?p=3'
    },
    modified: '2019-04-20T16:36:30',
    modified_gmt: '2019-04-20T16:36:30',
    slug: 'slug-title',
    status: 'publish',
    type: 'post',
    link: 'http://localhost/wordpress/2019/04/20/slug-title/',
    title: {
      rendered: 'title'
    },
    content: {
      rendered: '\n<figure class="wp-block-image"><img ' +
        'src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/sirius.jpg" ' +
        'alt="" class="wp-image-4" ' +
        'srcset="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/sirius.jpg ' +
        '370w, ' +
        'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/sirius-217x300.jpg ' +
        '217w" sizes="(max-width: 370px) 100vw, 370px" ' +
        '/></figure>\n',
      protected: false
    },
    excerpt: {
      rendered: '',
      protected: false
    },
    author: 1,
    featured_media: 0,
    comment_status: 'open',
    ping_status: 'open',
    sticky: false,
    template: '',
    format: 'standard',
    meta: [],
    categories: [
      3
    ],
    tags: [],
    _links: {
      self: [Array],
      collection: [Array],
      about: [Array],
      author: [Array],
      replies: [Array],
      'version-history': [Array],
      'predecessor-version': [Array],
      'wp:attachment': [Array],
      'wp:term': [Array],
      curies: [Array]
    },
    _embedded: {
      author: [Array],
      'wp:term': [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

But as you can see there is no featured_media. Do I have a misunderstanding about featured_media? I made my post with an image like you can see in `content.rendered`

Comment: Well, I don't think the post actually has a featured image. The one in the `content.rendered` is an image added using the Image block. You set the featured image via the "Set featured image" link in the "Featured Image" meta box, even when using the block editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP Rest API - How to get featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231137/wp-rest-api-how-to-get-featured-image)

Comment: @evgenifotia, I'm glad the comment helped. And just to be clear, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNY0B.png) is what I meant, which is for the block editor. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ I have wordpress in french that's why I haven't realized that meta box thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't set featured image for your post ,so return 0 in feature image obj. after set it you can use featured image obj.

for example: I wrote this with PHP, you can upload this to another host and display the images of the WordPress website that you specified in the URL variable on those hosts.

```
$url = 'url of your wordpress website';
function Json_Data_Decoder($query){     
    global $url;
    $json = file_get_contents($url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/'. $query);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    return $data;
}
function Get_Media($post_media){
    global $url;
    $json = file_get_contents($url.'/wp-json/wp/v2/media?include='.$post_media);
    $medias = json_decode($json);
    $featured_image = $medias[0]->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url;
    return $featured_image;
}

$posts = Json_Data_Decoder('posts');
foreach ($posts as $post){
    
    // get media 
    $post_media = $post->featured_media;
    $featured_image = Get_media($post_media);
    
    echo 
    '<article class="post image">
            <img src="'.
                $featured_image .
            '">
    </article>';
}
```

Comment: In WordPress's REST API, the `featured_media` should be automatically set, without needing a plugin. It'll return the featured image's ID or `0` if there's not a featured image.

Comment: you're right. I edited this answer.